# How can I assign a piece of text full of double quotes to a String variable in Java

Tags: java, string, escaping

There is a piece of text which contains a lot of double quotes:

```
"fdfdfs"sdf)sdfds*fsd"/fsdfsd\"f""we"r32ed**s(fsdF"sdF"s'sfsD"FSD"'f"'SD"FsD"f'"sdF"Sf'Sf"S
```

And now I want to assign it to a String variable in Java. What should I do? **I know backslash may work, but what if the text contains thousands of double quotes? In python, I can use single quote or triple quotes to easily handle this issue. Is there any similar method in Java (and in Android Studio) to fix this issue?**

Edit: I want to copy the text, and directly "drop"(paste) it into a String.Just like in Python I can satisfy the requirements by just a pair of triple quotes:

```
String s= 
a="""
"fdfdfs"sdf)sdfds*fsd"/fsdfsd\"f""we"r32ed**s(fsdF"sdF"s'sfsD"FSD"'f"'SD"FsD"f'"sdF"Sf'Sf"S
"""
print(a) # outcome:"fdfdfs"sdf)sdfds*fsd"/fsdfsd\"f""we"r32ed**s(fsdF"sdF"s'sfsD"FSD"'f"'SD"FsD"f'"sdF"Sf'Sf"S
```

Comment: "*And now I want to assign it to a String variable in Java*" - in what way? Copy-paste? Read from file?

Comment: @Fureeish I prefer to a Copy-paste method, since I may have to deal with a lot of such texts, which will be pretty unconvinient if I do it in the "reading from file" way.

Comment: The above  suggested similar questions can partly answer my question. I may adopt those solutions if I have to. But I would like to see something more convinient and new ways if possible, since those answers were posted 2 years ago.

Comment: I believe that any decent IDE should automatically escape any quotes directly copy-pasted into a String. IntelliJ does so, at least.

Comment: @Fureeish You are right! I just find those texts can be printed out as I expect......My wrong. It seems that I misunderstood the concept of "escape". Thank you ！

Comment: If you have text with thousands of characters, you are better off putting it in a text file and reading that file as a resource.  I don’t see much benefit to having a string literal of that size in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 13 has a preview feature called [Text Blocks](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/355) which allow exactly* that:

```
String s = """
           <your text here>
           """;
```

You'll have to [enable preview features](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/preview-language-and-vm-features.html) for that and the feature may or may not change in future versions.

In earlier versions of Java there is no such functionality.

*Well, mostly. Text blocks are not really *raw* strings but allow double quotes at least.